# Build script for an operating system written in C++

Tags: bash, compiler

I recently started following the [James M Kernel Dev tutorials](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/index.html) and was able to create an operating system in C++.

[Here](https://github.com/aswinmohanme/Just-Another-OS/tree/4032a258febd2a80948c4b34e507f717accc19d3) is the source on GitHub.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Is my coding style ok?
2. Is it wrong to write bash scripts for building the project?

**JOSMake.sh**

```
#
# Build File for JOS
#
# To Build
#    bash build.sh
# To Run
#   bash run.sh

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# JOS uses assembly to build the bootsector
# Compile the boot Sectors in boot
echo "==============================================="
echo "-------- Building Boot Sectors ----------------"
cd boot
# Run the Make Script inside the boot directory
bash buildboot.sh
cd ..
echo "==============================================="
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Compile the C++ Sources into Respective Objects
# Compile main.cc
echo "==============================================="
echo "--------- Compiling C++ Sources --------------"
g++ -c -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -m32 -o main.o main.cc
mv main.o build
# Run scons to build the Entire Lbrary of C++ Files
cd include
rm *.o
scons
# Move all Object Files into Build Directory
cp *.o ../build
cd ..
echo "==============================================="
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## When Everything is Finished Link together the Objects into a Kernel File
echo "==============================================="
echo "--------- Linking ----------------"
cd build
# require ld , link.ld
ld  -T '../link.ld' -m elf_i386 -o  kernel.jos *.o
# Clean Up After Build
#rm *.o
echo "==============================================="
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## When Everything is Finished Run the Kernel
qemu-system-i386 -kernel kernel.jos
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of repeated statements like this:

> ```
> echo "==============================================="
> ```

I suggest adding a helper function, for example:

```
print_hr() {  # hr - as in horizontal rule
    echo "==============================================="
}
```

The advantage of this is if you later decide to change the length of the `=` in the line, you can change it in one place.

---

Instead of entering into sub-directories with `cd dirname` and later stepping back with `cd ..`, I recommend to use sub-shell environments with `(...)`. For example, instead of this:

> ```
> cd include
> rm *.o
> scons
> # Move all Object Files into Build Directory
> cp *.o ../build
> cd ..
> ```

Do like this:

```
(
    cd include
    rm *.o
    scons
    # Move all Object Files into Build Directory
    cp *.o ../build
)
```

Notice that there is no more `cd ..`.
Working directory changes in a `(...)` sub-shell environment are only in effect within.

---

This maybe a matter of taste, but I find that the many comment lines like this are just noise, and make the script hard to read, I suggest to remove them:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not *wrong* to use a Bash script to build your project, but it is  suboptimal and unconventional.  Usually, a makefile is preferred, since Make can compare timestamps and rebuild just the objects that need to be rebuilt.

There are other advantages to makefiles as well.  For example, a common [convention](//stackoverflow.com/q/5541946/1157100) would be to define variables like

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -m32 $(EXTRA_CXXFLAGS)
```

Then, you would have the flexibility to run `make EXTRA_CXXFLAGS=-O2` to compile with `-O2` without having to edit the script.

---

A lot of your script's sequences of operations seem complicated and error-prone.  For example:

> ```
> cd include
> rm *.o
> scons
> # Move all Object Files into Build Directory
> cp *.o ../build
> cd ..
> ```

When your script changes directories, that's a bit of global state information that you need to keep track of.  That makes the script "brittle" — deleting or rearranging a few lines of the script can have massive effects on all subsequent commands.  If you need to change directories, use a subshell as @janos suggested.  Better yet, avoid changing directories at all, if possible — and you should be able to build a simple project like this without jumping around.

Why are there .o files in the `include` directory?  By convention, a directory named `include` would only contain `.h` header files that are included elsewhere, and don't need to be compiled (unless you are using [precompiled headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html) — but that's not the case here).

Why copy the .o files into the `../build` directory?  Find some way to get the compiler to produce them in the right place the first time (using the `-o` option).  Copying is inefficient, messes up timestamps, and leaves unnecessary junk.

---

Your script violates the Single Responsibility Principle:

> ```
> ## When Everything is Finished Run the Kernel
> qemu-system-i386 -kernel kernel.jos
> ```

If you advertise your script as a build script, then it should be just that.  Imagine you were packaging this software as a component in a Linux distribution.  Having such a line in the build script would be a serious annoyance.

Comment: Thanks ! I will dump the bash script and Rewrite it in make .