# Makefile for a x86 operating system in C++

Tags: c++, makefile, make

I recently had submitted my [bashscript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112606/build-script-for-an-operating-system-written-in-c) for building an OS for review and got valuable feedback, so I rewrote the entire script for a makefile:

**Makefile**

```
# Make File for Bulding Ultron

# Sets up the Assembler
AS := nasm
ASFLAGS := -f elf
ASFILES := $(wildcard kernel/boot/*.s kernel/arch/*.s)
ASOBJECTS := $(ASFILES:.s=.s.o)

# Compile C++ Files
CC := g++
CCFLAGS := -c -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -m32 -I./sdk/include
CCFILES := $(wildcard *.cc sdk/lib/*.cc)
CCOBJECTS := $(CCFILES:.cc=.o)


# Linker
LINKER := ld
LINKERFLAGS := -m elf_i386 -T link.ld

# The Final Product will be ultron.img in the build directory
all: ultron.img

# Ultron.img : It is the Final Product formed by linking all the object files together
ultron.img : $(ASOBJECTS) $(CCOBJECTS)
        $(LINKER) $(LINKERFLAGS) -o build/$@ $^

# Run the Kernel : First Make the Kernel and then run it
run: ultron.img
        qemu-system-i386 -kernel 'build/ultron.img'

# Assemble the Assembly Files into object Files
# This Assembles all the Files into thier respective object files
# $< : Names the first prerequiste
# $@ : Names the current Target
%.s.o: %.s
        $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@

# Compile the C++ Files into corresponding object Files and place it in same directory
%.o: %.cc
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ $<

# Clean this Mess
clean: $(ASOBJECTS) $(CCOBJECTS)
        $(RM) $^
```

This is my first makefile and I have a couple of questions:

1. Should I make the makefile as verbose as it is now?
2. Is my coding style Ok?
3. What are the things that I should keep in mind while writing makefiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Dependency Propagation**

One thing that's missing is dependency propagation. So each `.o` file will be recompiled only if its corresponding `.cc` file has changed. This is good, I don't want to have to recompile `foo.o` just because I changed `bar.cc`. However, what if both `foo.cc` and `bar.cc` include some other file `quux.h`, and you changed some of the function signatures. Currently, neither `foo.o` nor `bar.o` will be recompiled! This is bad. However, you don't want to manually have to go through and add:

```
bar.o : quux.h
foo.o : quux.h
```

Since that is tedious, error-prone, and unmaintanable. You want to make the compiler do this for you.You can start with reading about [automatic prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Prerequisites), but rather than follow the guidelines there, note that gcc can both build the `.o` files and generate the `.d` files concurrently with [`-M`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-M-1178) (check out all the `-M*` arguments).

**Targets**

`run` and `clean` should be `.PHONY` targets.

I also like to get in the habit of setting `.DEFAULT_GOAL` instead of just making sure that `all` is at the top. You never know.

**Comments**

Very helpful for the most part. But I would omit these:

```
# $< : Names the first prerequiste
# $@ : Names the current Target
```

People who don't know what those mean likely won't understand anything about the makefile anyway, not sure the comments will help. Those are very commonly used.

Comment: Thanks . I was experiencing the problem with dependency propagation. I would change the Function signature in the Header and to see the Output I would have to run make clean , and then compile again , which was pretty tedious . I will Update the MakeFile Soon :D

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, the `make` variable `CC` is used for the C compiler and `CXX` for the C++ compiler. I would recommend changing

```
CC := g++
```

to

```
CXX := g++
```

Similaly, `CFLAGS` is traditionally used for C compiler flags and `CXXFLAGS` is used for C++ compiler flags. I would recommend changing

```
CCFLAGS := ....
```

to

```
CXXFLAGS := ....
```

In the same vein, linker flags are usually defined using `LDFLAGS`. I would recommend changing

```
LINKERFLAGS := -m elf_i386 -T link.ld
```

to

```
LDFLAGS := -m elf_i386 -T link.ld
```

You can see the names of the traditional `make` variables at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html.